# Can't retrieve data from access database to DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, datagridview

I saved DataGridView data to an Access database using `Save_IndivTestResult()`. `TestResult` contains XML data. When I try to read the data back from Access database to DataGridView2 using `Load_Bank()`, all the data is displayed in a cell and not as a table. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
Private Sub Save_IndivTestResult()

    con = New OleDbConnection(Strcon)

    Try

        Dim yearmonthcode As String = ComboBox2.Text & MonNum & Lbl3.Text

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText)
        Next
        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            dt.Rows.Add(DataGridView1(0, x).Value, DataGridView1(1, x).Value, DataGridView1(2, x).Value)
        Next
        Dim dss As New DataSet
        dss.Tables.Add(dt)

        Dim stroledbSave As String = "INSERT INTO Tb_TestResult (YMC, TestResult) VALUES (@YMC, @TestResult)"

        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(stroledbSave, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ymc", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = yearmonthcode
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TestResult", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dss.GetXml
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Load_Bank()

    ds.Reset()
    con = New OleDbConnection(Strcon)
    con.Open()
    stroledb = "SELECT TestResult  FROM Tb_TestResult WHERE (Code = " & TSTextBox2.Text & ") AND (Month = '" & TSComboBox1.Text & "') AND (Year = '" & TSComboBox2.Text & "')"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(stroledb, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Tb_TestResult")
    con.Close()
    RichTextBox1.Text = ds.GetXml
    Dim temp As New IO.StringReader(RichTextBox1.Text)
    Dim XML As New Xml.XmlTextReader(temp)
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    ds1.Reset()
    ds1.ReadXml(XML)
    DataGridView2.DataBindings.Clear()
    DataGridView2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Datasource", ds1, "Tb_TestResult"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason to save it as xml and not actual data fields in the first place.  Why not use a parameterized query instead off string concatenations when retrieving data, and have you inspected ds1 after ds1.ReadXml to ensure that the XML is being parsed correctly and in the expected DataSet/DataTable structure?

Comment: The number of columns in my data is not predetermined  and the user determines the number of columns. I'm sure the data is loaded in the dataset because I first inserted it in a rich text box and then put it in the datagradview. When I hover the mouse over the datagrid cell, the data is displayed in the XML structure.

Comment: 2 questions 1). Do you have any pre-defined columns in your grid? 2). Have you put a breakpoint in after the readxml and actually inspected your dataset?  Sounds to me like either the dataset isn’t parsed correctly or there’s something in the column definitions tripping up

Comment: in datagridview2 that shows data from database i have not any pre-defined column. after readxml i put break point. there is some error :    Item In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user. String

Comment: 2)DeclaringMethod {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."} System.InvalidOperationException 3)  XmlResolver Write Only Properties are not supported System.Xml.XmlResolver
is there any way to fix it? Or do I have to change the  the method of storing data?

Comment: To me sounds like the ReadXML is failing.  So that would suggest that there is something wrong in the way your constructing when you're saving it.  Perhaps there is something in the schema being generated via dss.GetXML that can't be inferred when your attempting to read it.  Maybe start with comparing the Schema after constructing it and before the read xml call